# What is $L^2(\Omega)/\mathbb R$?

Tags: lp-spaces

I've [encountered this space in a book](https://books.google.de/books?id=CKYJBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA10&lpg=PA10&dq=temam+%22proposition+1.2%22+%22has+all+its+first-order%22&source=bl&ots=0pxJWRd2Ji&sig=ohVHXLOQaaM3S8yVhn9AWVNXWkk&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpua77we7OAhWFfiwKHbrqCq4Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=temam%20%22proposition%201.2%22%20%22has%20all%20its%20first-order%22&f=false) (see Proposition 1.2) and don't understand what is meant. It's a notation I only know from [quotient spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(linear_algebra)), but I can't make sense of that here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On page 11 in your link it is written that this is the space of all function orthogonal to the constant functions,

$$\{p\in L^2(\Omega) :\int_\Omega p\, dx = 0\}$$

Comment: This seems to be a very informal definition of a quotient space. What are the equivalence classes?  My best guess is that it would be two functions are in the same equivalence class if they differ by a constant, so that you can always find one in the equivalence class aware that integral is 0.

Comment: @Paul I just copied what is written in the book. There they don't seem to view this as a quotient, but as a symbol denoting the set I wrote down (which is well defined).

Comment: Yes.  I'm just trying to understand the connection to a quotient space, to relate it to OP's previous knowledge.  The notation is likely this way for a reason.

Comment: @Paul sure, look at the equivalence classes $\{f + c:c \in \mathbb{R}\}$

Comment: I didn't found that definition cause it occurs after its first usage. Thanks, Thomas.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the Stokes (and similarly Navier-Stokes) problem in $\Omega$
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
-\mu\Delta u + \nabla p & = f,\\
\nabla \cdot u & = 0,
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
with a presecribed boundary condition on $u$.
For any solution $(u,p)$ of the problem and any $\bar{p} \in \mathbb{R}$, $(u, p+\bar{p})$ is also a solution. Therefore the solution (if exists) is unique up to an isomorphism in $L^2(\Omega)$. The solution space $L^2(\Omega)$ for pressure is thus decomposed into a direct sum
$$L^2(\Omega) = \mathbb{R} \oplus (L^2(\Omega)/\mathbb{R}),$$
and the average-removed pressure is then uniquely determined in the space
$$L^2(\Omega)/\mathbb{R} = \{q \in L^2(\Omega): (q,1)_{0,\Omega} = 0\}.$$

Comment: While [Thomas answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1911075/47771) provides what I was looking for, I guess your answer is the main motivation for the introduction of $L^2(\Omega)/\mathbb R$ of the author of the referenced book.